# How to call a method which having SelectEvnet as argument?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

guys i'm passing SelectEvent as the argument into a method  (for ajax purpose).now how can i call that method in another method . ?

Comment: I think you need a clearer question.

Comment: method with selectEvent as an argument is not a method expression, its an action listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can call it like any other method in java. However, if the method depends on the selection event e.g. the component which triggered the event, you have to be careful.

If the method does not depend on the SelectionEvent you can call it like

```
mySelectionListener(null);
```

Or you create ne new SelectionEvent

```
SelectionEvent myEvent = new SelectionEvent();
mySelectionListener(myEvent);
```